# how sizeof() works in pass by reference arguments

Tags: c, arrays, function, pointers

I passed a array to function and tried to find the length of the array . but the result was not expected . can anybody explain please?

```
int main()
{
     int array[10]={0};
     func(array);
     return 0;
}
void func(int arr[])
{
    printf("length of an array is %d ",(sizeof(arr)/sizeof(arr[0]));
}
```

it gives the answer 2.
when I tried the same operation inside main function it works fine (answer is 10).
//using gcc complier in linux

Comment: There is no pass by reference in C. Therein lies your answer.

Answer (score 3):

Seems to me that the result is caused because `sizeof(arr) == 8` (size of a pointer on your PC) and `sizeof(arr[0]) == 4` because it is an integer hence `8/4==2`.

This declaration: `void func(int arr[])` tells the function to expect *a pointer to int* as argument.

It is not clear to me whether is possible to calculate the `sizeof` an array by reference. `C` functions accepting array reference as arguments always tend to receive their length too as argument.

The difference with `main()` function is that inside `main` `array` variable is of type `int[10]`, thus `sizeof` is able to get its length in bytes. In `func`, `arr` is of type `int*` so `sizeof` gives you only the length in bytes of a pointer.

Answer (score 2):

You are sending and recieving a array pionter, not the array.

while sending arg::

```
func(array[10]);
```

While Receiving arg:

```
void func(int array[10])
```

But it's not good to send the total array. So send and receive arguments like below.

```
func(array, arry_size);  //function call
void func(int array[], int length)  //defin
```

Comment: `int length` should better be `size_t length`.

Comment: @alk. By seeing the question we can say that he is new to c. Here you're right. bcoz better to follw standards.

Answer (score 1):

You have to remember that arrays decays to pointers. That means that in the function `func` the variable `arr` is not actually an array but a pointer. And doing `sizeof` on a pointers returns the size of the pointer and not what it points to.

You get the result `2` because you're on a 64-bit system where pointers are 64 bits (i.e. 8 bytes), an when divided by the size of `int` (which is 4 bytes) you get the result `2`.

Answer (score 0):

```
sizeof(arr)
```

is the size of a pointer, not the size of the block `arr` points to.

Answer (score 0):

When you pass an array into a function as a parameter, the array decays into a pointer to the beginning of the array. A pointer has no meta information stored in it unlike the array. A good practice is to pass the size to the function as an additional parameter.

```
void func(int *arr, int size);
```

Here's what C standard says (C99 6.3.2.1/3 - Other operands - Lvalues, arrays, and function designators):

> Except when it is the operand of the sizeof operator or the unary & operator, or is a string literal used to initialize an array, an expression that has type ‘‘array of type’’ is converted to an expression with type ‘‘pointer to type’’ that points to the initial element of the array object and is not an lvalue

So, once you pass it to the function - Inside the function, it's no more an array, it's a pointer.

Answer (score -1):

sizeof() operator returns the size of the data type. here int size is two.

Comment: i have mentioned the int array. thats y i have mentioned as int